# Get next or previous item to an object in a Swift collection or array

Tags: arrays, swift

What is the best way to identify the item that precedes or follows a specified object in a Swift array, while protecting against out of bounds errors?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A good way to approach this is with an extension on the Swift Array, or in this case a more generalised solution for all BidirectionalCollection objects, including arrays.

The following provides methods for getting the next or previous object after your specified object from an array, with an optional parameter if you want the function to loop at the ends of the array.

These functions return nil if the original object is not present in the Array, and also if you ask for the previous item to the first object or the item that follows the last object, for the non-looping functions.

```
//
//  Array+Iterator.swift
//

extension BidirectionalCollection where Iterator.Element: Equatable {
    typealias Element = Self.Iterator.Element

    func after(_ item: Element, loop: Bool = false) -> Element? {
        if let itemIndex = self.index(of: item) {
            let lastItem: Bool = (index(after:itemIndex) == endIndex)
            if loop && lastItem {
                return self.first
            } else if lastItem {
                return nil
            } else {
                return self[index(after:itemIndex)]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func before(_ item: Element, loop: Bool = false) -> Element? {
        if let itemIndex = self.index(of: item) {
            let firstItem: Bool = (itemIndex == startIndex)
            if loop && firstItem {
                return self.last
            } else if firstItem {
                return nil
            } else {
                return self[index(before:itemIndex)]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

**Usage:**
If you have an array of your children, and want to know the child that comes after Jane, you would use the following:

```
let nextChild = children.after(jane)
```

If you simply want to know whose turn it is to do the dishes, and Sammy did them last night, you'd instead use:

```
let dishwasherTonight = children.after(sammy, loop: true)
```

That way, if Sammy is the youngest child, his oldest sibling will be assigned to wash the dishes tonight as we loop back to the start of the array.

---

*Postscript: note re the comparison to endIndex in the code the [definition of that property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection):*

> You can access an element of a collection through its subscript by
>   using any valid index except the collection’s endIndex property. This
>   property is a “past the end” index that does not correspond with any
>   element of the collection.

Comment: I think you are prepared answer before asking question.lol.. Useful answer :)

Comment: Absolutely. In fact, Stack Overflow has an option to answer your own question at the point of submission, where you submit both Question and Answer at the same time. I was surprised to find there didn't seem to be an answer to this question on Stack Overflow so decided I'd add a tidy extension for anyone looking for one. :)

Comment: Yes useful for me also :) so that only this question on my fav list. Great, Thanks  bro :)

Comment: I would generalize this to a any `BidirectionalCollection` so that more types are supported (such as `ArraySlice`)

Comment: Good suggestion @Alexander. I've generalised to BidirectionalCollection.

Comment: Somehow i get sigseg from compiler (xcode 11.4.1) when using this. extending Array instead of BidirectionalCollection for the moment workarounds it.

Comment: one should note: _'index(of:)' is deprecated: renamed to 'firstIndex(of:)'_

Answer (score 19):

I propose a simpler and more thorough implementation:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Equatable {
    typealias Element = Self.Iterator.Element
    
    func safeIndex(after index: Index) -> Index? {
        let nextIndex = self.index(after: index)
        return (nextIndex < self.endIndex) ? nextIndex : nil
    }
    
    func index(afterWithWrapAround index: Index) -> Index {
        return self.safeIndex(after: index) ?? self.startIndex
    }
    
    func item(after item: Element) -> Element? {
        return self.firstIndex(of: item)
            .flatMap(self.safeIndex(after:))
            .map{ self[$0] }
    }
    
    func item(afterWithWrapAround item: Element) -> Element? {
        return self.firstIndex(of: item)
            .map(self.index(afterWithWrapAround:))
            .map{ self[$0] }
    }
}

extension BidirectionalCollection where Iterator.Element: Equatable {
    typealias Element = Self.Iterator.Element
    
    func safeIndex(before index: Index) -> Index? {
        let previousIndex = self.index(before: index)
        return (self.startIndex <= previousIndex) ? previousIndex : nil
    }
    
    func index(beforeWithWrapAround index: Index) -> Index {
        return self.safeIndex(before: index) ?? self.index(before: self.endIndex)
    }
    
    func item(before item: Element) -> Element? {
        return self.firstIndex(of: item)
            .flatMap(self.safeIndex(before:))
            .map{ self[$0] }
    }
    
    
    func item(beforeWithWrapAround item: Element) -> Element? {
        return self.firstIndex(of: item)
            .map(self.index(beforeWithWrapAround:))
            .map{ self[$0] }
    }
}
```

Comment: if simpler == fewerLinesOfCode ;)

Comment: And more readable... "get the index of the thing, if it exists, get the index after it, if that exists, get the element at that index"

Comment: @DuncanBabbage Check out my changes. Now all Collections benefit from all "after" methods, and BidirectionalCollections also get the "before" methods. Also, if you're going to make methods to get an item before/after another item, then you may as well the logic and also make methods to get an index before/after another index

Comment: I have added basic comments, it would be good if posts like this could have comments already, we need to encourage people to document their code more.

Comment: @Leon I would generally agree, but I would only use comments in places where no other mechanism works. But luckily in Swift, we have named arguments, and a convention that prefers descriptive method names. I think the signatures of these particular methods are fully self-documenting. Do you disagree?

Comment: I do (disagree), very much so, I was able to work out what each function did but it wasn't immediately obvious. A newer dev will have even less chance of getting it. That's the whole point of documentation. Ultimately, when writing the code, you are not the best person to judge if comments are needed or not and it does no harm at all to add comments when they're not necessary.

Comment: @Leon Actually, comments are not without harm. Every time they're used, their value has to be weighed up against their cost. Their main cost is the risk of going out-of-sync from the code, and misdirecting readers. " A newer dev will have even less chance of getting it. That's the whole point of documentation." That's not actually the case. Perhaps on an education post like this, that might be a good idea, but in general, comments are not there to "dumb down" the code for newer programmers

Comment: @Leon Any software project has to establish some minimum baseline of "assumed knowledge". We're not going to go around commenting how `if` statements work, for (an extreme) example. I analogize it to novel writing. Once you enter the domain of novel writing (akin to a software project), knowing english (akin to a programming language like Swift) is assuming knowledge. That may sound harsh, but really, it serves to elevate the level of discourse beyond constantly repeating the basics, for the portion of the community that may benefit from it

Comment: I think you've lost sight of the context here, I'm talking about posts such as this that contain multiple, somewhat obscure functions. Comments are supposed to be there to help people and are sometimes unnecessary, yes, but I didn't propose adding comments to explain `if` statements so why even bring that up? I'm a pretty experienced Swift developer and I believe comments would have helped me more easy understand these functions with a better degree of confidence. Is that not enough for you or do you want to debate this more?

Comment: I actually don't understand what's going on with the selector calls with map and flat map. Was this removed in later versions of swift ?

Comment: My previous comment was wrong. @theReverend Could you elaborate on your question? What do you mean with "the selector calls" ? What's a "selector call"?

Comment: Thank you @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, when you call  for example flatMap on the index "self.index(of: item).flatMap(self.safeIndex(after:))" How does this work?, As I understand it, flatMap is used to transform a collection.

Comment: @theReverend If you're using Xcode, option-click it to get more type information and documentation, or command click it to jump to definition. As it turns out, Collections are just one example of a type of thing (called a "monad", but don't let that scare you) that's flatMap-able. `Optional<T>`, `Result<T, E>`, `Promise<T>` and many other types are also monads, and have flatMap operations defined. In this case, it's [`Optional.flatMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap)

Comment: @theReverend `self.index(of: item)` returns an `Index?`. `self.safeIndex(before:)` takes an `Index` and returns an `Index?`. If we called `self.index(of: item).map(self.safeIndex(before:))`, we would get an `Index??` (a nested optional). Using flatMap does the unwrapping internally, so hte final result is a simple `Index?`. I'd recommend reading https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/an-aside-about-flatmap-and-monads.html

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica appreciate the response, this was the cause of my confusion: "Swift provides a common abstraction for doing it in one line: map. The map function on Array takes a function". I didn't know you could simplified it like that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Swift's factory methods?

try this to get a previous item to an object.

```
                let currentIndex = yourArr.index(of: "0")
                let previousVal = yourArr[currentIndex-1]
```

First get the index of object you want previous item for,
then get the item of that index-1.

Comment: This variant of what you posted (updated for current Swift syntax, and handling the option) would compile, but of course crashes with an out of bounds error:

```let yourArr = ["0"];
if let currentIndex = yourArr.firstIndex(of: "0") {
    let previousVal = yourArr[currentIndex - 1]
}```

The focus of the original question was "while protecting against out of bounds errors". :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    
    /// Finds next element of the array, returns nil if there is no next element
    func nextElement(element: Element, completion: @escaping(Element?)->()){
        let currentIndex = self.firstIndex { $0 == element}
        if let currIndex = currentIndex?.advanced(by: 1) {
            completion(currIndex >= self.endIndex ? nil : self[currIndex])
        }else{
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
    
    /// Finds prev element of the array, returns nil if there is no previous element
    func prevElement(element: Element, completion: @escaping(Element?)->()){
        let currentIndex = self.firstIndex { $0 == element}
        if let currIndex = currentIndex?.advanced(by: -1) {
            completion(currIndex <= self.endIndex ? nil : self[currIndex])
        }else{
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative for those that don't like working with indicies:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Equatable {
    typealias Element = Self.Iterator.Element
    
    func after(_ item: Element) -> Element? {
        var after: Element?
        var reverse = reversed().makeIterator()
        while case let next = reverse.next(), next != item {
            after = next
        }
        return after
    }
}
```

It iterates backwards, keeping track of the current item and breaking when it sees the item you wanted the one next of.