# Prev/Next object based on search string in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I got the follwing code from another answer but wanted to change is slightly to include a searchable string. I get an error at the following `where: { $0.id == searchString }`, which says  `Ambiguous reference to member '=='`. I assume this is due to the ambiguous nature of `item` but I might be wrong. How can I fix the function?

[Get next or previous item to an object in a Swift collection or array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340536/get-next-or-previous-item-to-an-object-in-a-swift-collection-or-array)

```
extension BidirectionalCollection where Iterator.Element: Equatable {
    typealias Element = Self.Iterator.Element

    func after(_ item: Element, loop: Bool = false, searchString: String) -> Element? {
        if let itemIndex = self.index(where: { $0.id == searchString }) {
            let lastItem: Bool = (index(after:itemIndex) == endIndex)
            if loop && lastItem {
                return self.first
            } else if lastItem {
                return nil
            } else {
                return self[index(after:itemIndex)]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func before(_ item: Element, loop: Bool = false, searchString: String) -> Element? {
        if let itemIndex = self.index(where: { $0.id == searchString }) {
            let firstItem: Bool = (itemIndex == startIndex)
            if loop && firstItem {
                return self.last
            } else if firstItem {
                return nil
            } else {
                return self[index(before:itemIndex)]
            }
        }
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code can work only if `Iterator.Element` has an `id` property, otherwise the `==` operator can't be applied.

So add a protocol and an appropriate constraint:

```
protocol HasId {
    var id : String { get }
}

extension BidirectionalCollection where Iterator.Element: Equatable, Iterator.Element: HasId {
    typealias Element = Self.Iterator.Element

    func after(loop: Bool = false, searchString: String) -> Element? {
        if let itemIndex = self.index(where: { $0.id == searchString }) {
            let lastItem: Bool = (index(after:itemIndex) == endIndex)
            if loop && lastItem {
                return self.first
            } else if lastItem {
                return nil
            } else {
                return self[index(after:itemIndex)]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func before(loop: Bool = false, searchString: String) -> Element? {
        if let itemIndex = self.index(where: { $0.id == searchString }) {
            let firstItem: Bool = (itemIndex == startIndex)
            if loop && firstItem {
                return self.last
            } else if firstItem {
                return nil
            } else {
                return self[index(before:itemIndex)]
            }
        }
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Vadian, you are correct. I would just suggest an edit to your answer just so it works properly - i think the piece `_ item: Elemet ...` is redundant since we are searching for the index in the `where` below.